# Selecting particular values from a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with only two columns. I would like to extract a small part out of it based on some condition on one column. Consider this as my dataset.

```
A    B
1    10
1    9
2    11
3    12
3    11
4    9
```

Suppose I want to extract only those rows which have values in B from 10 - 12. so I would get a new dataset as:

```
A    B
1    10
2    11
3    12
3    11
```

I tried using **df.loc[df["B"] == range(10, 12)]** but it dose not work, can someone help me with this?

Comment: basically .`loc` is not necessary here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.between`

```
In [1031]: df.loc[df.B.between(10, 12)]
Out[1031]:
   A   B
0  1  10
2  2  11
3  3  12
4  3  11
```

Or, `isin`

```
In [1032]: df.loc[df.B.isin(range(10, 13))]
Out[1032]:
   A   B
0  1  10
2  2  11
3  3  12
4  3  11
```

Or, `query`

```
In [1033]: df.query('10 <= B <= 12')
Out[1033]:
   A   B
0  1  10
2  2  11
3  3  12
4  3  11
```

Or, good'ol `boolean`

```
In [1034]: df.loc[(df.B >= 10) & (df.B <= 12)]
Out[1034]:
   A   B
0  1  10
2  2  11
3  3  12
4  3  11
```

Comment: Maybe add the commend one `df.loc[(df["B"]>=10)&(df["B"]<=12),:]`

Comment: and.`df[np.where((df["B"]>=10)&(df["B"]<=12),True,False)]`, sorry ,too lazy to writing the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more (not using `.loc()` or `.query()`) which looks more like the initial (unsuccessful) attempt:

```
df[df.B.isin(range(10,13))]
```